# using flock, open and close file to implement many readers single writer lock

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, flock

I've got a project that consist of multiple processes that can read or write into a single data base. I wish to implement single writer / multi readers locks synchronized by a lock file using the system calls flock/open/close.

Upon lock failure, any re-attempt to take the lock again, will be made by the higher level that requested the lock (unlike spin-lock).

Unfortunately, while testing this model, it failed on scenario of unlocking that wasn't preceded by locking. 
perhaps you can help me find what did i do wrong here:

```
// keep read and write file descriptors as global variables.
// assuming no more than 1 thread can access db on each process. 

int write_descriptor=0;
int read_descriptor=0;

int lock_write() {
    if((write_descriptor = open(LOCKFILE, O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0644))<0) {
        return LOCK_FAIL;
    }

    if(flock(write_descriptor, LOCK_EX)<0) {
        close(write_descriptor);
        write_descriptor = 0;
        return LOCK_FAIL;
    }
    return LOCK_SUCCESS;
}

int unlock_write() {
    if(!write_descriptor) {
        // sanity: try to unlock before lock.
        return LOCK_FAIL;
    }

    if(flock(write_descriptor,LOCK_UN)<0) {
        // doing nothing because even if unlock failed, we
        // will close the fd anyway to release all locks.
    }
    close(write_descriptor);
    write_descriptor = 0;
    return LOCK_SUCCESS;
}


int lock_read() {
    if((read_descriptor = open(LOCKFILE,O_RDONLY))<0) {
        return LOCK_FAIL;
    }

    if(flock(read_descriptor, LOCK_SH)<0) {
        close(read_descriptor);
        return LOCK_FAIL;
    }
    return LOCK_SUCCESS;
}

int unlock_read() {
    if(!read_descriptor) {
        // sanity : try to unlock before locking first.
        return LOCK_FAIL;
    }

    if(flock(read_descriptor, LOCK_UN)<0) {
        // doing nothing because even if unlock failed, we
        // will close the fd anyway to release all locks.
    }
    close(read_descriptor);
    read_descriptor = 0;
    return LOCK_SUCCESS;
}


int read_db() {
    if(lock_read() != LOCK_SUCCESS) {
        return DB_FAIL;
    }
    // read from db
    if(unlock_read() != LOCK_SUCCESS) {
        // close fd also unlock - so we can fail here (can i assume that ?)
    }
}

int write_db() {
    if(lock_write() != LOCK_SUCCESS) {
        return DB_FAIL;
    }
    //write to db.
    if(unlock_write() != LOCK_SUCCESS) {
        // close fd also unlock - so we can fail here (can i assume that ?)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this process multithreaded? If so, this won't work because file locks are owned by processes, not threads.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Hi. as I've mentioned in the question, i assume each process has only 1 thread that deals with the lock (and that's why i could use global variables.

Comment: Can you be more precise about how it failed exactly. (Also, why is this tagged 'multithreading'?)

Comment: The code reached 'unlock_read' method, and the read_descriptor was equal to 0. this means that the 'lock_read' wasn't working properly, or wasn't called at all...

Comment: Wait. Why do you use different descriptors for read and write? Why not use a single variable? You said only a single thread was accessing the database, right? You either have a bug in code not shown or you are incorrect describing how this code is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both `lock_read` and `lock_write` add this as the first line:

```
assert ((read_descriptor == 0) && (write_descriptor == 0));
```

In `unlock_read`, add this:

```
assert (read_descriptor != 0);
```

And in `unlock_write`, add this:

```
assert (write_descriptor != 0);
```

And change code like:

```
if(flock(read_descriptor, LOCK_SH)<0) {
    close(read_descriptor);
    return LOCK_FAIL;
}
```

to:

```
if(flock(read_descriptor, LOCK_SH)<0) {
    close(read_descriptor);
    read_descriptor = 0;
    return LOCK_FAIL;
}
```

Do the same for the write code so that any time a descriptor is closed, the corresponding global is set to zero. (You really should use -1 for an invalid file descriptor since zero is legal.)

Make a debug build and run it. When an `assert` trips, you'll have your culprit.

Comment: Ok, os after I manage to reproduce the problem, it seems that it derived from referring to file_descriptor=0, as invalid value in my code. therefore, it artificially fail to unlock the file after locking it. Right now i've got an executable that reproduce the problem 100% of the time (meaning that on every occasion, the chosen file descriptor is zero ) , so i wonder what is the policy for choosing values for file descriptors ?

Comment: I've also verified that the first 3 non negative numbers (0 1 and 2 ) are reserved for stdin stdout and stderr. for some reason, it's not the case in my project. any idea why ?

Comment: @Zohar I'd have to see the design of your entire project to understand why, but some piece of code you have is not respecting that reservation. For example, it might be closing file descriptor zero and not re-opening a new stdin.